# Using html entity &nbsp in react hyperscript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to do something like

`h(Modal.Title, "&nbsp;")`
where h is the react-hyperscript method used in javascript.

I want that the html renders

```
<span class="abc">&nbsp;</span>
```

But it is actually doing:

```
<span class="abc">&amp;nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to render HTML entities, or any raw HTML for that matter, you need to use React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property:

```
h(Modal.Title, {dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {__html: "&nbsp;"}})
```

Read more about it in the React documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).